# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hmmlearn' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pip, jupyter, hmmlearn

I keep trying to `import hmmlearn as hmm` and even though i have tried installing it several ways, inlcuding the ways i have seen on other stack overflow pages or on github, I still keep getting this error.

In the terminal shell, it says that I have already downloaded it. I tried `pip install hmmlearn, pip3 install hmmlearn, conda install hmmlearn,  python -m pip install --user hmmlearn`

All of these are successful, however still in Jupyter notebook I keep getting this error. I even tried running a cell above:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install hmm learn
```

And still it does not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is that a typo in the last command? There is a space between `hmm` and `learn`. Was that also inb the command that you ran?